# Rails 4.0.13 assets url missing prefix and digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4, assets, digest

I've started working on a rails 4.0.13 app and we're trying to move the assets to a CDN

the problem appears on our staging server , the generated url are missing the prefix and digest

**Ex**:
`https://xxyyzz.blob.core.windows.net/stylesheets/application.css`

on my local machine using the same environment as on the staging server everything works fine

**Ex**:`https://xxyyzz.blob.core.windows.net/c532aef6b12d99b3ce3f05b4fc17c02d8a682b13/application-dd1ee03f18e6ee4df65b6a21d8cfcdeb.css`

**config/environments/dev_1.rb** :

```
...
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_tags = [CustomTagger::USER_TOKEN_LAMBDA, CustomTagger::PROCESS_PID]
  config.cache_store = :redis_store, RedisStores.new.url(db: 3), { expires_in: 1.day, driver: :hiredis }
```

**config/application.rb** :

```
...
 config.assets.enabled = true

 config.assets.precompile = Proc.new do |filename, path|
   case
   # JS
   when /application-.+\.js/ =~ filename then true
   when filename == 'vendor.js' then true
   # CSS
   when filename.end_with?('master-default.css') then true
   when filename == 'application.css' then true
   # IMG
   when /assets\/images\// =~ path then true
   # Exclude everything else.
   else false
   end
 end
 config.asset_host = 'https://xxyyzz.blob.core.windows.net'

 # Each environment must have a different asset path (the SHA1 digest of
 # Rails.env + Rails.application.revision).
 #
 # See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration.
 # See https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb#L174-L186
 config.after_initialize do
   ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
     self.assets_prefix = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(Rails.env + Rails.application.revision)
   end unless Rails.env.development?
 end
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
 config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Sendfile, 'HttpMethodNotAllowed'
```

Has anyone else encounter this ?

Comment: Is `config/environments/dev_1.rb` the environment file for your staging server?  I'm assuming so, but you mention two environments, but your post only includes one file (whose name doesn't match either one).  I thought as long as you have `config.assets.digest = true`, you should get fingerprinting.

Comment: Yes dev_1 is the environment used . I don't know where you got the impression about 2 environments . I've also thought that config.assets.digest = true should add the fingerprint ...

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that this is one environment and working differently on local and remote servers.  Sounds like a deploy issue... are you certain that everything on the local server is in your repository and has been deployed as expected to the remote server?

Comment: Yes , I've added loggers to check the configs/environment values , everything seems to be the same . Also checked from the rails console .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what the problem was https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15873

It seems rails checks if the file is present in public/assets and if it's not it doesn't set the prefix & digest .

similar issue : https://serverfault.com/questions/638905/does-rails-4-asset-path-helper-uses-asset-prefix

A possible solution would be keeping the manifest.json file in the repo
or adding a deploy task that precompiles only the manifest file .
https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/107